# Why was this not-a-real-question declined?

Tags: discussion

I flagged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261023/onupdate-doesnt-get-called-on-device as "not a real question," since the OP answered it himself as "I don't know what has happened but it started working". I believe it does not bring anything to SO to have such questions that **ask nothing and teach nothing**.

It was declined. I do mind the flag weight hit, but it is a minor issue to me compared to the fact that I will take other hits if I mark other such questions, which I will do unless I get an explanation I understand to that "decline".

I do understand that human error happens, and *maybe* I happen to be right with my perception and the person who declined wrong. However, I assume by default I am missing a good reason here for lack of experience, and hence I ask  "what was not right in my reasoning"?

Comment: Rather than flag it as not a real question (since it is a real question), you should flag the answer given by the OP. As `Not an answer` or `other`. Then the moderators will see that answer and see that the question most likely has no answer and can be closed.

Comment: In a perfect world the OP would know what they did to fix it ad post a proper answer themselves. Then again in a perfect world the OP wouldn't have had an error in the first place.

Comment: @Paul Richard Oldbridge is 100% correct. From our dashboard, we only see the specific question or answer that you flag. The moderator that dismissed it probably saw "NARQ" under a perfectly valid, well written question. Next time, make sure to draw our attention to the post that made you say "Uh oh", or use "other" to explain the context.

Comment: Granted, seeing such an odd flag would _usually_ arouse our suspicions enough to go investigate more, but on days where we receive upwards of 1,200 flags (such as yesterday), we don't always do that.

Comment: "Too localized" is also a very applicable close reason for "Oops, it was a typo" or, "Huh, I restarted my IDE and now it builds." In the flagging dialogue, this is found under "it doesn't belong here".

Comment: JOY!  It's THIS question, ***YET AGAIN!***

Answer (score 10):

So, to summarize comments and mark this as answered:

- when a question is problematic due to interactions with an answer, it's better to either use "other" to explain the context or flag the answer itself as "not an answer".
- "too localized" is a typical close reason for this type of question
- moderators only see the specific question/answer flagged
- moderators have an incredible amount of work and should be considered with awe for doing such a great job ;)

Comment: Hah, I'll mark it answered in two days :D